# nx: How to keep external dependencies per app?

Tags: nrwl-nx

I'm trying to understand NX's handling of external dependencies (not intra-workspace dependencies). Looking at the (long...) discussion in [nx issue #1777: package.json per app](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1777), it seems that:

- NX supports globally-maintained dependencies - in a single `package.json` at the workspace's root
- Folks want to have certain dependencies only for specific project, at least at packaging/deployment time

  - For example, back-end projects shouldn't have all the front-end libraries that front-end projects use
- There are suggestions that maybe projects can define their own dependencies, or maybe a subset of the global packages to use
- But, I couldn't find any actual conclusion or guidance.

**So, Question:** If I want to handle most dependencies globally, but keep some dependencies local only to specific packages, how should I manage that?

Details: I'm using nx 14.5.2, with TypeScript, node.js and npm.

**Edit:** As noted in comments, nx adds a filtered-to-relevant package.json to compiled results under dist folder (for applications built with `@nrwl/node:webpack`, need to add `"generatePackageJson": true` - [ref](https://nx.dev/packages/node/executors/webpack)). However, how do I know which of the built libraries until `dist/libs` I need to pack into the deployed app? Is there a feature similar to the filtered package.json?

Comment: Thats something that nx does automatically. When you build a package, the resulting package.json in the dist folder, should only have the dependencies for that package.

Comment: How would nx know which dependencies of the global `package.json` a specific package uses? Does it perform an analysis of the code, like it does for infra-workspace dependencies? If so, great - I'll be sure to test and report here.

Comment: @lbueker: I tested, and indeed this works! Put that as an answer and I'll gladly accept. Note: For applications built with `@nrwl/node:webpack`, I needed to add `"generatePackageJson": true` [ref](https://nx.dev/packages/node/executors/webpack)

Comment: However, how would I know which of the libraries I need? I see webpack adds refs to `./libs/...`, so I guess I could copy all of them - but is there a mechanism to resolve just the libs used by the app, like the filtered package.json?

Answer (score -1):

add workspaces to your main package.json like this

```
"workspaces": [
  "apps/*",
  "libs/*"
]
```

and then you can create package.json in your applications/libraries, your apps dependencies are linked to the parents package.json

Example (apps/server/package.json):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.7.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
```

then your packages will be installed in root package.json directory

read more at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces

its not related with nx itself, and perhaps not recommended with nx. but you can use it to grow your apps (without nx?)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out, though I'd need to upgrade my npm first - currently using v6...

Comment: yourwelcome, i will be glad to hear if it was helpful